# #autocomplete_path becomes invalid with % placeholder

Tags: entities, ajax

I'm writing an autocomplete-equipped field widget, and obviously, am installing a menu item

```
$items['MYMODULE/autocomplete'] = array(...)
```

to handle the search requests. For cleaner javascript code though, I would like to also pass the delta to the request, but as soon as I start fiddling with wildcard placeholders, such as:

```
$items['MYMODULE/autocomplete/%delta'] = array(...)
$items['MYMODULE/autocomplete/%delta/get'] = array(...)
```

the field loses the autocomplete functionality. What am I missing?

Comment: I'm not sure, but if you define `$items['MYMODULE/autocomplete']` as a menu callback, and you have no other menu items with 'MYMODULE/autocomplete' in them, it will respond to MYMODULE/autocomplete as well as MYMODULE/autocomplete/something or even MYMODULE/autocomplete/something/else/entirely; all with those additional path elements sent to your callback as arguments.

Comment: Yes, that's true, however you still have to declare them in hook menu, as in `page arguments => array(...)`. Thanks. That's a good lesson, although as I can see now, there seems to be no way to tag the json response with delta. Too bad.

Comment: actually, no, you don't.  easiest off the cuff case example is on your website go to `node/1/edit/foo/bar/baz/bing` and it will goto the node edit page for node 1 (assuming you have a node with nid 1 anyway :).  eg, drupal will find a best case match, with those extra arguments passed (and here ignored) to the page callback function.